# sequelize update with one to many

Tags: sequelize.js

I want to update my parent table and child table with use of foreign key, But when I perform below code, my parent table get updated

```js
  const supplier = await Supplier.findOne({
            where: {
                id: req.params.userId
            }
        });
        if (!supplier) {
            return res.status(404).send({ 
                status : "400",
                message: "Supplier Not found." 
            });
        }
        const supplierupdate =  Supplier.update(
            {
                firstName: req.body.firstName,
                lastName: req.body.lastName,
                email: req.body.email,
                roleType: req.body.roleType,
                uniqueCode: req.body.uniqueCode,
                mobileNumber: req.body.mobileNumber,
                isActive:1,
                deliveryAt : req.body.deliveryAt,
                organization_name : req.body.organization_name,
                supplier_locations :req.body.address
            }, 
            { 
                include:[{
                    model: db.supplier_locations,
                    as: 'supplier_locations', 
                    where : {supplierId : 15}
                }],
                where: {
                    id: req.params.userId
                },
               
                
            }
        );
```

I want to update my both tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`update` does not support `include` option so you have to update them separately.